# Print multiple Sheets and Sheet Ranges with hidden areas in one Print Job Excel VBA

Tags: excel, export-to-pdf, vba

This is similar to another post I saw but different enough that I feel I needed to ask the question.  I have a sheet ranges that I want to Export to a PDF.  But here is where it gets difficult.  One sheet that I need to print does not fit on the entire print area so what I need to do is print part of the sheet (Range) on one page and have the leftover columns print to a different page.  Normally this would just need to be a separate range but I need to keep the leftmost columns for context of that second range.  So the second page needs to have two print ranges on one page, is that possible?  Or, can I somehow print the second page with a hidden area, i.e. removing the columns that were printed on the first page?  If I went with this latter solution I would need to unhide those columns after the print job finished.  I want to keep all of the printing exported to one PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I did finally figure this out with what I think is the simplest solution.  I copied the page twice onto separate worksheets and then simply hid the areas that did not need to be printed.  I then delete the worksheets which always ask the user for permission, not the best but it works.  As an enhancement I could safe to a separate workbook in the %temp% directory.  That way it would not ask permission to delete as no deletion would be necessary.

ADD.  I did not realize this but I can easily turn off the alerts in VBA and solve that display pop up problem.